# Class Mageplaza\\helloworld\\Controller\\Index\\Index\Interceptor does not exist

Tags: magento2.3.4

I am working on a `CRUD` model , I have followed same steps as in this article https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/how-to-create-crud-model-magento-2.html but at the end when I hit `http://<myhost.com>/helloworld/index/index` its gives me an error 
`" Class Mageplaza\\helloworld\\Controller\\Index\\Index\Interceptor  does not exist "`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you have injected a new class in the constructor and its interceptors are missing

Run this command in your `magento_root` terminal

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Comment: Thanks it works !!